# How do I use attributeModifiers on Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I use attributeModifiers on a minecraft server? When I paste the command below the sword says it has the modifiers, but attacking something its like a normal diamond sword.

LAN server works fine. Though my brother can't connect half the time. We've fixed that by moving to a server.

Command I used:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:20,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:894654,UUIDMost:2872}]}
```

I've tried:
Changing the UUID,
Different commands (anything without modifiers work)
Different game-modes

Here is my server.properties if it's relevant:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Fri Jul 13 09:56:17 PDT 2018
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
broadcast-console-to-ops=true
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=3
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=false
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=true
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=true
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=false
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
prevent-proxy-connections=false
use-native-transport=true
enable-rcon=false
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: That command works fine for me, both in 1.12.2 and in 1.13-pre8 (if I remove ` 1 0 `). Is that `server.properties` file the current one? It contains no seed. I don't know if that should fill itself or not. Also `server-ip` is empty. I'm also unsure there if it's needed and if it fills itself. You have `online-mode` set to `false`, in the wiki it's `true`. I don't know what that does. Maybe it could be related to your brother's connection issues? The wiki also has "`broadcast-console-to-ops=true`", which should be unrelated and "`use-native-transport=true`", which I don't know.

Comment: But in general, `server.properties` should be unrelated to this issue. Can you try a different example command including attribute modifiers that you find online? And if you throw the item on the ground that you get with this command and then run `entitydata @e[type=item,r=5] {}`, what's the output?

Comment: I found the issue. I have a paste program installed that allows me to copy more than one items. The AUTO capitalize setting was interfering causing generic.Attackdamage

Comment: Then please post that as answer (with more detail preferably so that it can help other users) and mark it as accepted using the checkmark.